# How to debug VueJS getElementById issue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am using a VueJS single File component with the following template:

```
<template>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div id="hottable"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
</template>
```

And the following script:

```
<script>
//import all handsontable deps
export default {
  props: ['jsondata'],
  data () {
      return {}
  },
  methods: {
    populateTable: function() {
      var container = document.getElementById('hottable')
      console.log('container: ' + container)
    }
  },
  watch: {
    jsondata: function () {
      this.populateTable()
    }
  }
}
```

In the browser I can see that

```
<div data-v-270950bf id='hottable'></div>
```

exists, but when I run the code I get the following in the console:

```
container: null
```

I cant for the life of me work out why the container is null

Comment: You should not try to access DOM directly, of course it will be unreliable because this element is not there by the time you are trying to access it.

Comment: @dfsq do you suggest I call populateTable (and access the DOM) inside a 'mounted' method?

Comment: I suggest never to access DOM directly like you are doing right now. Even in mounted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to work fine: https://jsfiddle.net/wostex/63t082p2/47/

But it's not the best practice if you manipulate DOM manually. It limits your possibilities with reactive properties.

```
<div id="app">
  <child></child>
</div>

new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    components: {
    'child': {
      template: `
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div id="hottable"></div>
            </div>
        </div>`,
      mounted() {
        let c = document.getElementById('hottable');
        console.log(c);
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: OK point taken. However I still get component is null when I try to access from mounted. I will need to look into wrappers for vue-handsontable as the vanilla js handsontable examples access the dom directly.

Comment: @proximacentauri you can also access component template tag like this: `this.$el`. I've not tested this, but I guess this approach should work for handsontable library: https://jsfiddle.net/wostex/63t082p2/48/